# Nuxt.config.ts : Module '"nuxt"' has no exported member 'defineNuxtConfig'. when importing 'defineNuxtConfig'

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I created a Nuxt 3 project, my nuxt.config.ts looked like this :

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false,
    },
  },
  ssr: false 
  
})
```

This works with that.

But i wanted to use .env variable so i read that i need to add :

```
env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
```

When i add it to the nuxt.config.ts, after the "ssr", i got the error :

"Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'env' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'"

So i read that most of people have a import of defineNuxtConfig so i wanted to add it to my file :

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false,
    },
  },
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  
  ssr: false 
})
```

But now i have the error "Module '"nuxt"' has no exported member 'defineNuxtConfig'"

Any ideas ? :D

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Having the same issue :)

Answer (score 4):

The nuxt package has changed. You need to replace this

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";
```

with this

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try to run `nuxt build`

I got a similar error, but only because I blew away `.nuxt` (was troubleshooting something else). Running `nuxt build` cleared everything up.